# How to sort by index values then plot pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm plotting this dataframe of 1-5 stars and it works fine.

> 5 4424
>
> 4 2177
>
> 1 1529
>
> 3 1070
>
> 2 800

However, i want to sort the **indices** in ascending order - "1,2,3,4,5", not plot it by the actual values:
[image: kk]

the code that plots:

```
j.sort_index(by='stars').plot(kind='bar', rot = 1, figsize=(15,6))
```

I want the indexes to come in ascending order - 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: If change `j.sort_index(by='stars')` to `j.sort_index()` how working?

Comment: @jezrael yay! works!

Comment: @jezrael thx u so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove parameter `by` from `sort_index` for sorting by default index values:

```
j.sort_index().plot(kind='bar', rot = 1, figsize=(15,6))
```